# Enter more than one ingredient for a recipe

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

[image: Recipe form]

This is a project to display recipes in addition to performing many operations on recipes such as deleting, adding and modifying. When adding a new recipe I want to add a set of ingredients and each ingredient has a name and quantity, but, I don't know how a label can be made for more than one ingredient.

If we look at the picture for the last two fields, where the name of the component and its quantity are located, here I can only add one component, the question is how can I add two components?

`createRecipe.vue`:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-layout row>
        <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
          <h2 class="btn-style">Create Recipe</h2>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
      <v-layout row>
        <v-flex xs12>
          <form @submit.prevent="onCreateRecipe">
              <v-layout>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                <v-text-field
                  name="id"
                  label="Id"
                  id="id"
                  v-model="id"
                  color="#43A047"
                  required
                >
                </v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>

            <v-layout>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                <v-text-field
                  name="title"
                  label="Title"
                  id="title"
                  v-model="title"
                  color="#43A047"
                  required
                >
                </v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-layout>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                <v-text-field
                  name="imageUrl"
                  label="ImageUrl"
                  id="imageUrl"
                  v-model="imageUrl"
                  color="#43A047"
                  required
                >
                </v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-layout>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                <img :src="imageUrl" height="300px">
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-layout>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                <v-text-field
                  name="description"
                  label="Description"
                  id="description"
                  v-model="description"
                  color="#43A047"
                  multi-line
                  required
                >
                </v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-layout>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                <v-text-field
                  name="ingredientsName"
                  label="IngredientsName"
                  id="ingredientsName"
                  v-model="ingredientsName"
                  color="#43A047"
                  multi-line
                  required
                >
                </v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
             <v-layout>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                <v-text-field
                  name="ingredientsQuantity"
                  label="IngredientsQuantity"
                  id="ingredientsQuantity"
                  v-model="ingredientsQuantity"
                  color="#43A047"
                  multi-line
                  required
                >
                </v-text-field>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-layout row>
              <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
                <v-btn
                  class="green darken-1 color"
                  :disabled="!formIsValid"
                  type="submit"
                >
                  Create Recipe
                </v-btn>
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </form>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      id:"",
      title: "",
      imageUrl: "",
      description: "",
      ingredientsName: "",
      ingredientsQuantity: "",
    };
  },
  computed: {
    formIsValid() {
      return (
        this.id !== ""&&
        this.title !== "" &&
        this.description !== "" &&
        this.imageUrl !== "" &&
        this.ingredientsName !== ""&&
        this.ingredientsQuantity !== ""
      );
    }
  },
  methods: {     
    onCreateRecipe() {
      if (!this.formIsValid) {
        return;
      }
      const recipeData = {
        id:this.id,
        title: this.title,
        description: this.description,
        imageUrl: this.imageUrl,
        ingredientsName:  this.ingredientsName,
        ingredientsQuantity: this.ingredientsQuantity
      };
    // Here we call the setter to put the Data inside it
      this.$store.commit('createRecipe', recipeData)
      const stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(recipeData);
      // console.log("S: ", stringifiedData);
      localStorage.setItem("recipe", stringifiedData);
      console.log("We got : ", JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("recipe")));
      // this.$store.dispatch('createRecipe', recipeData).then(() => //alert('STH') or whatever you 
        want to do after you add recipe)
    }
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.btn-style {
  color: #43a047;
}
.color {
  color: #fafafa;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make an array of ingredients which would contain the ingredientName, ingredientQuantity.

```
ingredients: [
  {
    ingredientsName: "",
    ingredientsQuantity: "",
  },
  {
    ingredientsName: "",
    ingredientsQuantity: "",
  }
]
```

Loop over this array to display all these ingredients.

You will need to add a new button to add a new ingredient, and on that button click, attach this event below.

```
addIngredient () {
  this.ingredients = [...this.ingredients , {
    ingredientsName: "",
    ingredientsQuantity: ""
  }]
}
```

Comment: (https://github.com/hibayoussef/OneStoreRecipes)
This my code>>>When I click on "create a recipe", I want to enter more than one ingredient, not one

Comment: Do you want to send the project on your Email?

Comment: I send email to you.please check your Email.